# Java VNC Applet

Tags: java, applet, vnc

Does any one know of an opensource Java VNC server, that can be run from a web page, so requiring no installation on the server end, possibley applet based.

Comment: To clarify a little: you want the *server* to run from a webpage, not the *client* ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://vncj.com/default.aspx
Once you get it setup you wont know how you lived w/o it. The server and the client are using the same .jar file all in the html page pointing where your listen client is at.

Answer (score 2):

A signed Java applet (or application) can use the Robot class to get screenshots of the current window and use this for remote control.  It will never be very efficient, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Tight VNC only offers an applet based client, and not server, and GSVNCJ is closed source.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is wrong — it is perfectly possible to build a VNC server in Java. Yes, Java is sandboxed, but this doesn't mean it cannot access screen contents if you want it to!

Comment: The accepted answer has changed. That makes part of your answer obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [GSVNCJ](http://vncj.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/).  It requires no installation, works through firewalls, and works like vnc.  They actually use VNC behind the scenes, I think.